# Is it a good practice to store the result of a O(1) hashet lookup when used multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, design-patterns, dictionary

I am using a hashset structure for mapping purposes: `Dictionary<string, string>`.

If I need to read the value of myHashset["key1"] many times in successive statements, is it a good practice to store the first lookup using a local variable?

**Edit**: no other thread would modify the dictionary so it is not an important criterion.

Thanks!

Comment: same goes for repeatedly calling getters when you know the result won't change.

Comment: @Thilo: That's not really comparable. A property getter is much cheaper and readable than what the OP is asking.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth depends on the getter. It could be exactly the same if the getter looks up a dictionary of comparable type and size.

Comment: @JonHanna: Sure, it depends. But getters are supposed to be cheap and not do much.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes, and mostly are inlinable and could even have the equivalent work done for us by the compiler if it spots we're doing what amounts to hitting the same place in the heap memory each time. Mostly.

Comment: @JonHanna: If you notice a performance degredation when repeatedly accessing a getter, go ahead and save it to a local variable. However, performance is not the only reason I wrote my answer. Using a local variable in case of the dictionary doesn't just improve the performance by a tiny bit, but more importantly, it increases readability of your code. And this advantage doesn't exist when you replace a property getter with a local variable as the property getter already is readable. That's why I am of the opinion that the two cases can't be compared

Comment: @DanielHilgarth well, that's the one reason why I might read a property into a local - what's e.g. a general-purpose `Count` to one class may have a particular meaning within a method, and I can name accordingly. For the most part I agree though.

Comment: @JonHanna: I think we both agree that readability is the more important point here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

`O(1)` simply states that the operation takes the same amount of time, no matter how many items are there.
This *doesn't* mean, that the time it takes is as fast as simply accessing a local variable.

Additionally, consider the following:

1. Accessing a local variable is much more readable
2. Normally, you want to have error handling or even use `TryGetValue` when accessing a value in a dictionary by its key. When using a local variable, you can keep this code at one place and don't have to smear it across the complete method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

- it avoids multiple O(1) lookups which are time-consuming
- it's much more readable than writing `dictionary["key"]` each time

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice for at least two reasons:

- Dictionary isn't truly O(1). The data is internally divided in small collections, and the Dictionary knows in which collection to search thanks to the hashcode. Still, there's a internal collection enumeration involved, and therefore the operation isn't free (though not expensive)
- The value may be modified from another thread. Keeping a reference helps making your code thread-safe and preventing unexpected results.

Comment: Why is that not O(1)? The time won't increase when you increase the number of those collections.

Comment: Dictionary is only degrading into worse than O(1) if there are a lot of hash-collisions. Otherwise the Dictionary class is truly O(1).

Comment: The msdn documentation says "close to O(1)" and "retrieval depends on the quality of the hashing algorithm"

Comment: @Thilo Its best-case is O(1), its average case is so close to O(1) as makes no difference. Its worse case is O(n) and slow at that (in this case searching through a list would be faster). The O(n) case indicates a really bad hash-code or a type of DoS attack where you deliberately trigger it, so 99% of the time you can think of it as pretty much O(1), though you should understand how the O(1) scenario comes about.

Comment: @Thilo Experiment with keys of `class BadKey{public int Value; public override bool Equals(object o){return o.Value == Value;} public override int GetHashCode(){return 0;}}` which is valid but very bad. Put a lot of keys of that into a dictionary (different values for `Value`), then fix it to `public override int GetHashCode(){return Value;}` and see O(n) become O(1) again.

Comment: @Blam as indeed I say at the end. The point isn't to be fair, the point is to have a quick, easy, and easily understood means to demonstrate the worse-case. Indeed, the point is almost to be unfair.

Answer (score 1):

Doing O(1) operations n times is O(n)!

It's a minor optimisation, but not every minor optimisation is a premature one. It will indeed save time.

> Edit: no other thread would modify the dictionary so it is not an important criterion.

Not in the case at hand perhaps, but in terms of what is good practice, we have to consider wider cases than just the one at hand - part of what makes something "good practice" is that it covers a wide number of cases with similar code that we depart from only when we know why we are doing so.

Without threading, our reasons are:

1. We are hitting the same code repeatedly with the same result.
2. The compiler isn't likely to realise that and rewrite to a single call for us.
3. It can increase readability.

The last point is worth considering. Every naming of a variable is an opportunity to make code self-documenting. Which is clearer as to what is going on:

```
CheckUpdated(dict[passedValue.split('\t')[1].Trim().ToUpperInvariant()]);
MarkLastCheckTime(dict[passedValue.split('\t')[1].Trim().ToUpperInvariant()]);
return GetStatus(dict[passedValue.split('\t')[1].Trim().ToUpperInvariant()];
```

Or:

```
var purchaseOrderCode = dict[passedValue.split('\t')[1].Trim().ToUpperInvariant()];
CheckUpdated(purchaseOrderCode);
MarkLastCheckTime(purchaseOrderCode);
return GetStatus(purchaseOrderCode);
```

I'm being a bit deliberately cryptic in the first case and I should really have done some of that work just once even if I kept hitting the same dictionary, but the lesser effect in real code is greater because it's a source file full of real code rather than a four-line example.

With threading, it becomes a matter of:

1. If we need to interleave with possible changes, we can't do this.
2. Otherwise, it removes a lot of the risks that come from threading, because we're working on a local and know it will be the same local throughout.

Therefore, while some threading cases mitigate against this approach, and awful lot insist upon it, and it's no longer an optimisation but essential for correctness.

It does become more complicated knowing which situation we are in, and considering other threads - because there are cases where we do want to allow the object in question to change if another thread updated the dictionary. But mostly we really want to make sure we keep dealing with the same object in the face of changes from other threads.

So, while not important here, it's still a reason for it being good practice generally.

Answer (score 0):

Yep...

You yourself have the answer. It will help and save micro seconds and CPU cycles. :)